# Regex for recipe ingredients -- ignoring adjectives and extraneous words

Tags: python, regex

I've been working on a regex to parse lists of recipes from various online sources, and I've been having trouble with having the regex ignore adjectives and qualifiers in the recipes.

For example, if the recipe calls for "1 rounded tablespoon paprika," I want my regex to ignore "rounded" and return "1," "tablespoon," and "paprika." To that end, I've come up with:

`(\d\/?\d?) ([\w]+?)?? ?(cup|tablespoon|teaspoon)? ([\w\s]+)`

Which seems to work well so long as there is a measurement. But for something like "1 egg" or "2 green onions," it doesn't match.

Is there a way to make the regex not only match when there isn't a measurement, but put the ingredient (i.e.,"egg") in the same group (group 4) as ingredients with a measurement?

Comment: Why not use a natural language API?

Comment: In truth, because I've been teaching myself python for about three months now and I don't know how. Do you think something like the nltk (just googled) would be better for this kind of problem? It's certainly something I would be interested in learning, but I'd hoped to make a fairly simple command line tool to showcase what I've learned so far, rather than dive into a whole new subject.

Comment: It would likely do a better job of separating relevant and irrelevant information, which seems to be your focus here. Regex is hard-coded and doesn't do well on changing information, typos, etc. NLP and AI is much better suited for such tasks.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the advice! I've been meaning to look into AI/machine learning stuff anyway; it's why I picked python.

Comment: Regex is best suited for string manipulations when the content or string form is static or known. For example, validation, extracting known formats, etc.

Comment: Use `spacy`, it has easy to use feature to extract patterns based on PoS, that also supports regex.

Comment: First thing which came into my mind is: Why regex and not [Prolog](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog). Old language, but still useful, if you are interested in the logic rather than learning how to use a specific NLP library.

Comment: But there is a big difference between "1 tablespoon" and "1 rounded tablespoon" from a culinary perspective and I personally would not be doing this.

Comment: That's true for a recipe, but I'm trying to build a grocery list off of a bunch of recipes. The idea is to have a command line feature where you can build a grocery list from urls as you go about your day, then print it out at the end when you go to the store. So it just needs to know a rough estimate of all the materials. I might even add something where it ignores certain common ingredients like salt so they don't clutter up the list.

Answer (score 0):

Better include the spaces also in the brackets, then they're only matched together. Gives you two matches for "rounded": With and without space after it, so just use the second one:

```
>>> re.findall("(\d\/?\d?) (([\w]+?) )?((cup|tablespoon|teaspoon) )?([\w\s]+)", "1 rounded tablespoon paprika")
[('1', 'rounded ', 'rounded', 'tablespoon ', 'tablespoon', 'paprika')]

>>> re.findall("(\d\/?\d?) (([\w]+?) )?((cup|tablespoon|teaspoon) )?([\w\s]+)", "1 tablespoon paprika")
[('1', 'tablespoon ', 'tablespoon', '', '', 'paprika')]

>>> re.findall("(\d\/?\d?) (([\w]+?) )?((cup|tablespoon|teaspoon) )?([\w\s]+)", "1 egg")
[('1', '', '', '', '', 'egg')]
```